# How do I condense this repetitive F# code?

Tags: f#

EDIT: possible solutions at bottom

I'm doing some data work where I need to be very careful about string lengths that will eventually be sent in fixed width text output, stored in limited size nvarchar fields, etc.  I want to have good strict typing for these rather than naked System.String types.

Suppose I've got some code like this to represent these, with a few useful module functions that play nicely with Result.map, Option.map, etc.

```
module String40 =
    let private MaxLength = 40
    type T = private T of string
    let create (s:string) = checkStringLength MaxLength s |> Result.map T
    let trustCreate (s:string) = checkStringLength MaxLength s  |> Result.okVal |> T
    let truncateCreate (s:string) = truncateStringToLength MaxLength s |> T
    let toString (T s) = s

    type T with
        member this.AsString = this |> toString


module String100 =
    let private MaxLength = 100
    type T = private T of string
    let create (s:string) = checkStringLength MaxLength s |> Result.map T
    let trustCreate (s:string) = checkStringLength MaxLength s  |> Result.okVal |> T
    let truncateCreate (s:string) = truncateStringToLength MaxLength s |> T
    let toString (T s) = s

    type T with
        member this.AsString = this |> toString
```

Obviously these are almost entirely repetitive with only the module name and max length different in each block.

What options are available to try and cut down on the repetitiveness here?  I would love to have something like this:

```
type String40 = LengthLimitedString<40>
type String100 = LengthLimitedString<100>

tryToRetrieveString ()   // returns Result<string, ERRType>
|> Result.bind String40.create
```

- T4 code generation doesn't seem to be an option for F# projects
- Type providers seem like overkill for this kind of simple templating, and as best as I can tell they can only produce classes, not modules.
- I'm aware of Scott Wlaschin's [constrained strings](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-more-semantic-types/) page, but I end up with roughly the same level of repetitive code in the 'Create a type', 'Implement IWrappedString', 'create a public constructor' steps he lists.

These code blocks are fairly short and it wouldn't be the end of the world to just copy/paste a dozen times for the different field lengths.  But I feel like I'm missing a simpler way to do this.

UPDATE:

One other note is that it's important that records using these types give information about what type they're carrying:

```
type MyRecord = 
  {
    FirstName: String40;
    LastName: String100;
  }
```

and not be something like

```
type MyRecord = 
  {
    FirstName: LimitedString;
    LastName: LimitedString;
  }
```

---

Tomas' answer, using the Depended Type Provider nuget library is a pretty good one, and would be a good solution for a lot of people who are fine with its behavior as-is.  I felt like it would be a little tricky to extend and customize unless I wanted to maintain my own copy of a type provider which I was hoping to avoid.

Marcelo's suggestion of static parameter constraints was a fairly productive path of research.  They give me basically what I was looking for -- a generic argument that is basically an 'interface' for a static methods.  However the kicker is that they require inline functions to operate and I don't have the time to evaluate how much that would or would not matter in my code base.

But I took that and altered it to use regular generic constraints.  It's a bit goofy to have to instantiate an object to get a max-length value, and fsharp type/generic code is just gross to look at, but from the module users's perspective it's clean, and I can easily extend this however I want.

```
    type IMaxLengthProvider = abstract member GetMaxLength: unit -> int

    type MaxLength3 () = interface IMaxLengthProvider with member this.GetMaxLength () = 3
    type MaxLength4 () = interface IMaxLengthProvider with member this.GetMaxLength () = 4


    module LimitedString =

        type T< 'a when 'a :> IMaxLengthProvider> = private T of string

        let create< 't when 't :> IMaxLengthProvider and 't : (new:unit -> 't)> (s:string) =
            let len = (new 't()).GetMaxLength()
            match checkStringLength len s with
            | Ok s ->
                let x : T< 't> = s |> T
                x |> Ok
            | Error e -> Error e
        let trustCreate< 't when 't :> IMaxLengthProvider and 't : (new:unit -> 't)> (s:string) =
            let len = (new 't()).GetMaxLength()
            match checkStringLength len s with
            | Ok s ->
                let x : T< 't> = s |> T
                x
            | Error e -> 
                let msg = e |> formErrorMessage
                failwith msg

        let truncateCreate< 't when 't :> IMaxLengthProvider and 't : (new:unit -> 't)> (s:string) =
            let len = (new 't()).GetMaxLength()
            let s = truncateStringToLength len s
            let x : T< 't> = s |> T
            x

        let toString (T s) = s
        type T< 'a when 'a :> IMaxLengthProvider> with
            member this.AsString = this |> toString


    module test =
        let dotest () =

            let getString () = "asd" |> Ok

            let mystr = 
                getString ()
                |> Result.bind LimitedString.create<MaxLength3>
                |> Result.okVal
                |> LimitedString.toString

            sprintf "it is %s" mystr
```

Comment: Represent the modules as an interface.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're suggesting.  Interfaces aren't going to provide functions compatible with, e.g. Result.map   It's the functional nature of entering and leaving the world of constrained strings that I'm interested in.  I'm willing to have more complicated constrained string code in order to have very simple and concise code USING the constrained strings.

Comment: It's just that what I've come up with so far is deeply repetitive and will be aggravating if I have a new 'common' function to apply to all string lengths

Comment: [This](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-more-semantic-types/) is literally the answer from Scott Wlaschin

Comment: You mentioned that T4 isn't an option in F#. It's not a clean option because F# project don't support T4. However, when I've needed T4 in F# for certain cases I created a C# project and generated from there. Ugly, but preferable to alot of typing. If you are on dotnet core then there non T4 tools like the one I wrote in abstinence of T4: https://github.com/mrange/carnelian .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use [Static Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters), as shown on the F#.Data package's [HtmlProvider](https://gist.github.com/JoseGonzalez321/257bc566dadc32180c12bb2e1046102f) example?

Comment: I don't think `ProvidedStaticParameter` can be used outside a Type Provider, and the OP stated that a Type Provider was not their preferred solution.

Comment: Statically resolved type parameters look interesting at first glance.  I'm not seeing anything that ties them to Type Providers in particular. Honestly I'm not sure I see any connection between the two links in this answer.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach, out of curiosity, would you see Type Providers as a viable path?  I've never gone down the road of implementing one before and don't really know if it is in fact overkill.  It seems like it's not the primary use case of a TP (strongly typing the schema of some external data source), but is this kind of simple templating another typical use?  Honestly, the reason I first rejected them was just that they can't produce modules and simple functions and seemed like they would force a more functional-unfriendly OOP type of programming

Answer (score 3):

I think the `BoundedString` type provider from the [Dependent type provider](http://blog.christopher-atkins.com/DependentTypesProvider/) project lets you do exactly what you need. Using the example from the project documentation, you can do e.g.:

```
type ProductDescription = BoundedString<10, 2000>
type ProductName = BoundedString<5, 50>

type Product = { Name : ProductName; Description : ProductDescription }

let newProduct (name : string) (description : string) : Product option =
  match ProductName.TryCreate(name), ProductDescription.TryCreate(description) with
  | Some n, Some d -> { Name = n; Description = d }
  | _ -> None
```

I don't know how many people use this project in practice, but it seems quite simple and it does exactly what you were asking for, so it might be worth a try.

Comment: yes, that definitely looks worth a try -- whether to use directly or just dig into the source code.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Using a touch of careful reflection magic, we can achieve a lot and get some really nice types. How about something like this?

```ml
module Strings =
    type [<AbstractClass>] Length(value: int) =
        member this.Value = value

    let getLengthInst<'L when 'L :> Length> : 'L =
        downcast typeof<'L>.GetConstructor([||]).Invoke([||])

    type LimitedString<'Length when 'Length :> Length> =
        private | LimitedString of maxLength: 'Length * value: string

        member this.Value =
            let (LimitedString(_, value)) = this in value
        member this.MaxLength =
            let (LimitedString(maxLength, _)) = this in maxLength.Value

    module LimitedString =
        let checkStringLength<'L when 'L :> Length> (str: string) =
            let maxLength = getLengthInst<'L>.Value
            if str.Length <= maxLength then Ok str
            else Error (sprintf "String of length %d exceeded max length of %d" str.Length maxLength)

        let create<'L when 'L :> Length> (str: string) =
            checkStringLength<'L> str
            |> Result.map (fun str -> LimitedString (getLengthInst<'L>, str))

open Strings

// === Usage ===

type Len5() = inherit Length(5)
type Len1() = inherit Length(1)

// Ok
LimitedString.create<Len5> "Hello"
// Error
LimitedString.create<Len1> "world"
```

Comment: I like the idea here but you probably also need to implement equality (for your sanity) and comparison (for sets and map keys).

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox Right, I just think this is a complete enough starting point. Those should be simple enough for you to add on your own.

Answer (score 2):

One option might be to use a single module for limited-length strings that uses curried parameters for the length-limit and the string itself, then just partially apply the limit parameter.  An implementation might look like this:

```
module LimitedString =
    type T = private T of string
    let create length (s:string) = checkStringLength length s |> Result.map T
    let trustCreate length (s:string) = checkStringLength length s  |> Result.okVal |> T
    let truncateCreate length (s:string) = truncateStringToLength length s |> T
    let toString (T s) = s

    type T with
        member this.AsString = this |> toString
```

Then, your modules for each length would still be required, but wouldn't have all the boilerplate:

```
module String100 =
    let create = LimitedString.create 100
    let trustCreate = LimitedString.trustCreate 100
    let truncateCreate = LimitedString.truncateCreate 100
```

**EDIT**

After reading the comment and the update to the original post, I would change my suggestion a bit.  Instead of defining the `T` type inside each module, I would have a specific struct-type single-case union for each string length at the top level.  Then, I would move to `toString` to the individual string modules.  Finally, I would add one more parameter to the `LimitedString` module to allow us to partially apply both the length and the specific single-case union type:

```
[<Struct>] type String40 = private String40 of string
[<Struct>] type String100 = private String100 of string

module LimitedString =
    let create length ctor (s:string) = checkStringLength length s |> Result.map ctor
    let trustCreate length ctor (s:string) = checkStringLength length s  |> Result.okVal |> ctor
    let truncateCreate length ctor (s:string) = truncateStringToLength length s |> ctor

module String40 =
    let create = LimitedString.create 40 String40
    let trustCreate = LimitedString.trustCreate 40 String40
    let truncateCreate = LimitedString.truncateCreate 40 String40
    let toString (String40 s) = s

module String100 =
    let create = LimitedString.create 100 String100
    let trustCreate = LimitedString.trustCreate 100 String100
    let truncateCreate = LimitedString.truncateCreate 100 String100
    let toString (String100 s) = s

type MyRecord =
    {
        FirstName: String40
        LastName: String100
    }
```

There's still a fair amount of boilerplate here, but I think this is in the ballpark for a solution using single-case unions and modules.  A Type Provider might be possible, but you would have to consider whether the added complexity outweighs the boilerplate.

Comment: I suppose that does cut down on the character count a bit but still has each creation function repeated for each module.  Actually, a bigger problem here is that any records containing these types lose any sense of what the constraint is.  I didn't really say that in my question, I'll update it to be clear.